# Why does it look like I can consume a value from an immutable BTreeMap?

Tags: iterator, rust, immutability

I'm doing an Exercism exercise wherein I need to invert a map of scrabble scores; map of scores => letters becomes map of letters => scores. I came up with the following Rust code:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

pub fn transform(h: &BTreeMap<i32, Vec<char>>) -> BTreeMap<char, i32> {
    h.iter()
        .flat_map(|(&score, letters)| {
            letters
                .into_iter()
                .map(move |l| (l.to_ascii_lowercase(), score))
        })
        .collect()
}
```

This works, but afterwards I realized it shouldn't. `h` is an immutable reference. `h.iter()` iterates over references to its entries, which should have the type `(&i32, &Vec<char>)`, but then I'm taking the `Vec` and consuming it with `into_iter()`. Rust does not complain, despite it being an immutable reference.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

After typing out the question, I figured out the answer. `IntoIterator` is implemented for `Vec`, but also for `&Vec` and `&mut Vec`. Rather than consuming the `Vec`, it consumes the reference and iterates over references to its elements. Very simple behavior, but I managed to do it in the most confusing way possible.